# Select counts from 2 different tables without subselect within subselect

Tags: mysql, select, count, subquery

I'm trying to do a count from multiple tables in the same query and the results for 2 of the counts are completely wrong. I have the following 3 tables used in this query:

```
CREATE TABLE `assignments` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `lead_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `buyer_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `refunded` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `date_assigned` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_refunded` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `leads` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `vertical_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `agent_id` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
    `status_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `completeness` enum('Partial','Complete') DEFAULT NULL,
    `freshness` enum('New','Duplicate') NOT NULL,
    `date_created` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `date_updated` int(11) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `verticals` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

What I want to do, is grab results and place them into a table like this:

```
Name        New Duplicate Partial Complete Total Assigned Refunded
Automotive  4   1         3       2        5     36       9
Education   16  7         9       14       23    36       9
```

The first 5 column numbers are correct. The problem is that the assigned and refunded column numbers are completely wrong. Here is my query:

```
select v.*,
(select count(*) from `leads` where vertical_id=v.id and `freshness`='New' and `date_created` between 1470009600 and 1471923227) as `new`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where vertical_id=v.id and `freshness`='Duplicate' and `date_created` between 1470009600 and 1471923227) as `duplicate`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where vertical_id=v.id and `completeness`='Partial' and `date_created` between 1470009600 and 1471923227) as `partial`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where vertical_id=v.id and `completeness`='Complete' and `date_created` between 1470009600 and 1471923227) as `complete`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where vertical_id=v.id and `date_created` between 1470009600 and 1471923227) as `total`,
(select count(*) from `assignments` where lead_id=l.id and `refunded`=0) as `assigned`,
(select count(*) from `assignments` where lead_id=l.id and `refunded`=1) as `refunded`
from `verticals` as v
left join `leads` as l on (l.vertical_id = v.id)
where l.date_created between 1470009600 and 1471923227
group by v.id
```

How can I correct this without using a subselect within the subselects (which would be terrible for performance)?

**EDIT: I believe I almost have this working, but there has to be a better way to write this query (also, it seems to be grouping the `assignments` by `lead_id`):**

```
select o.*,
(select count(*) from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `freshness`='New' and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) as `new`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `freshness`='Duplicate' and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) as `duplicate`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `completeness`='Partial' and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) as `partial`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `completeness`='Complete' and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) as `complete`,
(select count(*) from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) as `total`,
(select count(*) from `assignments` where `lead_id` in 
    (select `id` from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) and `refunded`=0) as `assigned`,
(select count(*) from `assignments` where `lead_id` in 
    (select `id` from `leads` where {$sql_column}=o.id and `date_created` between {$date_from} and {$date_to}) and `refunded`=1) as `refunded`
from {$sql_object} as o
```

Comment: can you provide some records for same ?

Answer (score 0):

```
select v.*,COUNT(CASE WHEN `freshness`='New' THEN freshness END) as new,COUNT(CASE WHEN `freshness`='Duplicate' THEN freshness END) as duplicate from `verticals` as v left join `leads` as l on (l.vertical_id = v.id) where l.date_created between 1470009600 and 1471923227 group by v.id
```

Hope this will help. try it.

Comment: This is not complete. It also addresses the columns which I already have working, and completely removes the 2 problematic columns I'm trying to focus on fixing from the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Given this data

```
/*
truncate table verticals;
INSERT INTO VERTICALS VALUES
(1,'Automotive'),(2,'Educational');

truncate table leads;
insert into leads values
(1,1,1,1,1,'Partial','New', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(2,2,1,1,1,'Partial','New', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(3,1,1,1,1,'Partial','Duplicate', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(4,2,1,1,1,'Partial','Duplicate', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(5,1,1,1,1,'Complete','New', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(6,2,1,1,1,'Complete','New', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(7,1,1,1,1,'Complete','Duplicate', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(8,2,1,1,1,'Complete','Duplicate', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(9,1,1,1,1,'Complete','New', 1470009600, 1470009600),
(10,1,1,1,1,'Complete','Duplicate', 1470009600, 1470009600);

truncate table assignments;
insert into assignments values
(1,1,1,0,1470009600, 1470009600),
(2,2,1,1,1470009600, 1470009600),
(3,3,1,0,1470009600, 1470009600),
(4,4,1,1,1470009600, 1470009600),
(5,5,1,1,1470009600, 1470009600);
*/
```

This query

```
select v.*,
SUM(CASE WHEN L.`freshness`='New' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `new`,
SUM(CASE WHEN L.`freshness`='Duplicate' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `duplicate`,
SUM(CASE WHEN L.`completeness`='Partial' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as `partial`,
SUM(CASE WHEN L.`completeness`='Complete' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)  as `complete`,
count(L.id)  as `total`,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.`refunded`=0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `assigned`,
SUM(CASE WHEN A.`refunded`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as `refunded`
from `verticals` as v
left join `leads` as l on (l.vertical_id = v.id) AND  (l.date_created between 1470009600 and 1471923227)
LEFT JOIN ASSIGNMENTS A ON A.LEAD_ID = L.ID
group by v.id
```

Results

```
+----+-------------+------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
| id | name        | new  | duplicate | partial | complete | total | assigned | refunded |
+----+-------------+------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
|  1 | Automotive  |    3 |         3 |       2 |        4 |     6 |        2 |        1 |
|  2 | Educational |    2 |         2 |       2 |        2 |     4 |        0 |        2 |
+----+-------------+------+-----------+---------+----------+-------+----------+----------+
```